# AngularJS Error: Requested keys of a value that is not an object. keys@[native code]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I got an error on mobile browsers and Safari, the project works normally on chrome and firefox with 0 errors.

```
Error: Requested keys of a value that is not an object.keys @[native code]
```

i'm using the following modules

```
'maticApp.controllers',
'maticApp.directives',
'checklist-model',
'ngRoute',
'ngCookies',
'ui.bootstrap'
```

i tried to remove file by file to determine the error but it's hopeless.
here is a link for the project http://matic.imenadigital.com/#/GetStarted

Thanks in advance

Comment: using for mobile apps? ionic?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the error,

`$http({ 
      method:'GET', 
      url: 'http://website.com/API', 
      param: 'limit = 10, sort_by=created:desc'
}).success(....`

The error was in the `params` key , you should write it as an object like 
`param: {limit : 10, sort_by: 'created:desc'`

or remove it and it will work fine.